# Android emulator closes app upon startup, LogCat gives multiple errors

Tags: android, eclipse

When I run the app off Eclipse, the emulator states "Unfortunately, (app name here) has stopped. LogCat gives multiple red warnings. I have typed the errors shown, below. I want to create a splash screen, and I have already written the code for it in xml files under the Res folder. What code should I write in the MainActivity.java in order to run the splash screen first?

```
05-22 11:49:22.121: D/AndroidRuntime(1575): Shutting down VM
05-22 11:49:22.121: W/dalvikvm(1575): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a38ba8)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): Process: com.example.apocalypse, PID: 1575
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apocalypse/com.example.apocalypse.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at com.example.apocalypse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-22 11:49:22.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you using `AppCompat`?

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
>   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

The stacktrace is clear. You need to use Theme derived from `Theme.AppCompat`

Example in manifeset

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

For more info read

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: ok. so I want a splash screen so what should be placed in the Mainactivity.java? I have already written the code in the xml files, I just need the code in the MainActivity to run the xml file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using the correct `Theme`. You are probably using the support library, and therefore you need to choose a `Theme` that inherits from `Theme.AppCompat` like that stacktrace says.

Comment: ok. so I want a splash screen so what should be placed in the Mainactivity.java? I have already written the code in the xml files, I just need the code in the MainActivity to run the xml file

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you are not extending the Theme.AppCompat in all the styles you defined.
style.xml files (or wherever you put yours) are normally spread on all the values-XX folders.

Comment: ok. so I want a splash screen so what should be placed in the Mainactivity.java? I have already written the code in the xml files, I just need the code in the MainActivity to run the xml file